# Error while inserting date - Incorrect date value:

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column called `today` and the type is `DATE`.

When I try to add the date in the format `'07-25-2012'` I get the following error:

> Unable to run query:Incorrect date value: '07-25-2012' for column

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As MySql accepts the date in y-m-d format in date type column, you need to `STR_TO_DATE` function to convert the date into yyyy-mm-dd format for insertion in following way:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(today)
VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('07-25-2012','%m-%d-%Y'));
```

If you want to select the date in different format other than Mysql format, you should try `DATE_FORMAT` function

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(today, '%m-%d-%y') from table_name;
```

Comment: Maybe it changed meanwhile, but according to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp it needs to be `%Y` for a 4-digit year parsing.

Comment: What to do if the Date is optional?

Answer (score 7):

You need to convert the date to YYYY-MM-DD in order to insert it as a MySQL date using the default configuration.

One way to do that is [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
insert into your_table (...)
values (...,str_to_date('07-25-2012','%m-%d-%Y'),...);
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally mysql uses this date format 'Y-m-d H:i:s'

Comment: No, that's for datetime type. For date type, it defaults to Y-m-d

Answer (score 3):

This is the [date format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in **'YYYY-MM-DD'** format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

Why do you insert '07-25-2012' format when MySQL format is '2012-07-25'?. Actually you get this error if the [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html) is `traditional/strict mode` else it just enters 0000-00-00 and gives a warning: `1265 - Data truncated for column 'col1' at row 1`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use YYYY-MM-DD format to insert date in mysql

Answer (score 2):

I had a different cause for this error. I tried to insert a date without using quotes and received a strange error telling me I had tried to insert a date from 2003.

[image: My error message:]

Although I was already using the YYYY-MM-DD format, I forgot to add quotes around the date. Even though it is a date and not a string, quotes are still required.

Comment: VALUES ('$rowt[my_date]') this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use "DATE" as a data type while you are creating the table. In this way, you can avoid the above error.
Eg:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (birth_date DATE);
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES('1967-11-17');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. It will work fine.

```
INSERT INTO table_name(today)  
VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('07-25-2012','%m-%d-%Y'));
```

Actually you cannot directly store date as a string, you first need to convert string to date in a proper format for which we use `STR_TO_DATE()` function, which needs two arguments, first is date as a string and 2nd one is date format in which you are passing your first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add a single or double quote. I noticed that you must add `""`, so MySQL uses it as string.

```
INSERT INTO table_name values 
 ("2001-11-09");
```

Answer (score 0):

**What worked for me is:**

To change date **DD-MM-YYYY** format:

```
E1001,John,Thomas,123456,01/09/1976,M
```

To **YYYY-MM-DD** format:

```
E1001,John,Thomas,123456,1976/01/09,M
```

And it works flawless.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in several other answers.