# Adding an additional field breaks my query

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

When I add an additional field  to my query, it fails. I have checked the spelling 20 or more times....I do not know what is wrong.. Please help!!

Working code BELOW

```
if(isset($_POST['UPDATE_RAW'])) {
    extract($_POST);

    $sql=mysqli_query($db,"update nma_raw set NMA_System='$nmasystem',NMA_Ticket_Number='$nmaticketnum',Tkt_Priority='$tktpriority',Created_On_Worklist='$createdonworklist',Create_Date='$createdate',Create_Time='$createtime',Days_Old='$daysold',Interval_Onlist='$intervalonlist',Check_Status='$checkstatus',Ticket_Status='$ticketstatus',Relate_Status='$relatestatus',WFA_TR_Num='$wfatrnum',Recent_WFA_Dispatch_Status='$recentwfadispatchstatus',Last_Owner='$lastowner',Entity_Status='$entitystatus',Entity='$entity',First_Cond_Type='$firstcondtype',Last_Cond_Type='$lastcondtype',State='$st',CLLI='$clli',Check_Active='$checkactive',Check_Jepd='$checkjepd' WHERE ID='$id'");

    if($sql) {
        echo "<script>alert('Updated SuccessFully');window.location.href='Active_Tkt_Qry_List_Frm_NMA.php';</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Some ERRORS');</script>";
    }
}
```

NOT WORKING CODE BELOW!

```
if(isset($_POST['UPDATE_RAW'])) {
    extract($_POST);

    $sql = mysqli_query($db,"update nma_raw set NMA_System='$nmasystem',NMA_Ticket_Number='$nmaticketnum',Tkt_Priority='$tktpriority',Created_On_Worklist='$createdonworklist',Create_Date='$createdate',Create_Time='$createtime',Days_Old='$daysold',Interval_Onlist='$intervalonlist',Check_Status='$checkstatus',Ticket_Status='$ticketstatus',Relate_Status='$relatestatus',WFA_TR_Num='$wfatrnum',Recent_WFA_Dispatch_Status='$recentwfadispatchstatus',Last_Owner='$lastowner',Entity_Status='$entitystatus',Entity='$entity',First_Cond_Type='$firstcondtype',Last_Cond_Type='$lastcondtype',State='$st',CLLI='$clli',Check_Active='$checkactive',Check_Jepd='$checkjepd', Resolved_Date='$resolved_date' WHERE ID='$id'");

    if($sql) {
        echo "<script>alert('Updated SuccessFully');window.location.href='Active_Tkt_Qry_List_Frm_NMA.php';</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Some ERRORS');</script>";
    }
}
```

HERE IS A PICTURE OF MY DB SCHEMA
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph6de.png)

HERE IS THE TOTAL PHP FILE

```
<?php include_once "header.php";?>
   <section class="content">

            <div class="page-body clearfix">
                <?php
                $id=$_REQUEST['id'];

                 $sql=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT NMA_RAW.*, NMA_RAW.Check_Status, NMA_RAW.Resolved_Date, NMA_RAW.Filtered_Date FROM NMA_RAW WHERE (((NMA_RAW.Check_Status)='OK') AND ((NMA_RAW.Resolved_Date) Is Null) AND ((NMA_RAW.Filtered_Date) Is Null)) AND NMA_RAW.ID = $id;");

                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

                ?> 
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">NMA Active Ticket Form</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>NMA System</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="nma_system" class="form-control" placeholder="NMA System" value="<?= $row['NMA_System']; ?>" name="nmasystem">    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>NMA Ticket Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nma_ticket_number" class="form-control" placeholder="NMA Ticket Number" value="<?= $row['NMA_Ticket_Number']; ?>" name="nmaticketnum"> 
                                </div>
                                 <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Ticket Priority</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="ticket_priority" class="form-control" placeholder="Ticket Priority" value="<?= $row['Tkt_Priority']; ?>" name="tktpriority">    
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Created On Worklist</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="created_on_work_list" class="form-control" placeholder="Created On Worklist" value="<?= $row['Created_On_Worklist']; ?>" name="createdonworklist">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Created Date</label>

                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                        </span>
                                      <input type="date" id="created_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Created Date" value="<?= $row['Create_Date']; ?>" name="createdate">
                                    </div>                                      
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Created time</label>
                                     <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="time" id="created_time" class="form-control" placeholder="Created Time" value="<?= $row['Create_Time']; ?>" name="createtime">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                           <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Days Old</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="days_old" class="form-control" placeholder="Days old" value="<?= $row['Days_Old']; ?>" name="daysold">    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Check</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="check" class="form-control" placeholder="Check" value="<?= $row['Check_Status']; ?>" name="checkstatus">    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Ticket Status</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="ticket_status" class="form-control" placeholder="Ticket Status" value="<?= $row['Ticket_Status']; ?>" name="ticketstatus">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                             <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Interval</label>

                                        <input type="text" id="interval" class="form-control" placeholder="Interval" value="<?= $row['Interval_Onlist']; ?>" name="intervalonlist">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Related Status</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="relate_status" class="form-control" placeholder="Relate Status"  value="<?= $row['Relate_Status']; ?>" name="relatestatus">    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>WFA TR Num</label>

                                        <input type="text" id="wfa_tr_num" class="form-control" placeholder="WF TR Num" value="<?= $row['WFA_TR_Num']; ?>" name="wfatrnum">

                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Recent WFA Dispatch Status</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="recent_wfa_dispatch_status" class="form-control" placeholder="Recent WFA Dispatch Status" 
                                                            value="<?= $row['Recent_WFA_Dispatch_Status']; ?>" name="recentwfadispatchstatus">    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Entity Status</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="entity_status" class="form-control" placeholder="Intity Status" value="<?= $row['Entity_Status']; ?>" name="entitystatus">    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Entity</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="entity" id="entity" class="form-control" placeholder="Entity"  value="<?= $row['Entity']; ?>" name="entity">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Last Owner</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="last_owner" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Owner" value="<?= $row['Last_Owner']; ?>" name="lastowner">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>First Cond Type</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="first_cond_type" class="form-control" placeholder="First Cond Type" value="<?= $row['First_Cond_Type']; ?>" name="firstcondtype">    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Last Cond Type</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="last_cond_type" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Cond Type" value="<?= $row['Last_Cond_Type']; ?>" name="lastcondtype">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>State</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="state" class="form-control" placeholder="State" value="<?= $row['State']; ?>" name="st">    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Check Active</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="check_active"  class="form-control" placeholder="Check Active" value="<?= $row['Check_Active']; ?>" name="checkactive">    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <label>Check Jepd</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="check_jepd" id="check_jepd"  class="form-control"placeholder="Check Jepd" value="<?= $row['Check_Jepd']; ?>" name="checkjepd">      
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>CLLI</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="clli" class="form-control" placeholder="CLLI"  value="<?= $row['CLLI']; ?>" name="clli">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Resolved Date</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                        </span>
                                      <input type="date" id="resolved_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Resolved_Date" value="<?= $row['Resolved_Date']; ?>" name="resolved_date">
                                    </div>   
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <label>Filtered Date</label>
                                     <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="date" id="filtered_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Filtered Date" value="<?= $row['Filtered_Date']; ?>" name="filtereddate">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>Filtered By</label>

                                    <input type="text" id="filtered_by" class="form-control" placeholder="Filtered by" value="<?= $row['Filtered_By']; ?>" name="filteredby">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <label>Restored Date</label>
                                     <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="date" id="restored_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Restored_Date" value="<?= $row['Restored_Date']; ?>" name="restoreddate">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                         <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                                  <label class="text-bold"> NMA Comments subform  </label>  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                              <hr>
                            <div class="form-group">

                            <?php
                            $io = mysqli_query($db,"select * from NMA_Comments where NMA_Tkt_Num='$row[NMA_Ticket_Number]'");
                            $tr=mysqli_fetch_assoc($io);
                            ?>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">  
                                    <label>NMA Ticket Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="NMA_Ticket_Number" id="nma_ticket_number" class="form-control" placeholder="NMA Ticket Number" value="<?php echo $tr['NMA_Tkt_Num']; ?>" >    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>NMA Notes</label>
                                    <textarea type="text" name="NMA_Notes" id="nma_notes" class="form-control" placeholder="NMA Notes"><?php echo $tr['NMA_Notes']; ?></textarea>
                                </div>
                                     <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label>NMA Note Date</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="NMA_Ticket_Date" id="nma_ticket_number" class="form-control" placeholder="NMA Ticket Number" value="<?php echo $tr['NMA_Note_Date']; ?>"> 
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">                                
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="UPDATE_RAW">  Save and Close</button>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                                <button class="btn btn-success" name="MOVE_TO_RESOLVED">  Resolved and Close</button>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" name="MOVE_TO_INHIBITS">  Inhibit and Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </section>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['UPDATE_RAW'])){
            extract($_POST);

            //print_r($_POST);
            $sql=mysqli_query($db,"update nma_raw set NMA_System='$nmasystem',NMA_Ticket_Number='$nmaticketnum',Tkt_Priority='$tktpriority',Created_On_Worklist='$createdonworklist',Create_Date='$createdate',Create_Time='$createtime',Days_Old='$daysold',Interval_Onlist='$intervalonlist',Check_Status='$checkstatus',Ticket_Status='$ticketstatus',Relate_Status='$relatestatus',WFA_TR_Num='$wfatrnum',Recent_WFA_Dispatch_Status='$recentwfadispatchstatus',Last_Owner='$lastowner',Entity_Status='$entitystatus',Entity='$entity',First_Cond_Type='$firstcondtype',Last_Cond_Type='$lastcondtype',State='$st',CLLI='$clli',Check_Active='$checkactive',Check_Jepd='$checkjepd', Resolved_Date='$resolved_date' WHERE ID='$id'");

            if($sql){
                echo"<script>alert('Updated SuccessFully');window.location.href='Active_Tkt_Qry_List_Frm_NMA.php';</script>";
            }
            else{
                echo"<script>alert('Some ERRORS');</script>";

            }


        }
        ?>

<?php
            if(isset($_POST['MOVE_TO_INHIBITS'])){

            extract($_POST);
            //$print_r($_POSt);
            $sql=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO nma_main_table SELECT * FROM nma_raw where ID='$id'");

            if($sql){
                echo"<script>alert('Updated SuccessFully');window.location.href='Active_Tkt_Qry_List_Frm_NMA.php';</script>";
            }
            else{
                echo"<script>alert('Some ERRORS');</script>";

            }
            // sql to delete a record
            $sql=mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM nma_raw WHERE ID='$id'");

            if ($sql){
            echo "Record Inhibited successfully";
            } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Error in deletion');</script>";
            }


            }
            ?>

<?php
            if(isset($_POST['MOVE_TO_RESOLVED'])){

            extract($_POST);
            //$print_r($_POSt);
            $sql=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO nma_main_table SELECT * FROM nma_raw where ID='$id'");

            if($sql){
                echo"<script>alert('Updated SuccessFully');window.location.href='Active_Tkt_Qry_List_Frm_NMA.php';</script>";
            }
            else{
                echo"<script>alert('Some ERRORS');</script>";

            }
            // sql to delete a record
            $sql=mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM nma_raw WHERE ID='$id'");

            if ($sql){
            echo "Record Resolved successfully";
            } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Error in deletion');</script>";
            }


            }
            ?>            


<?php include_once "footer.php";?>
```

Comment: What error did you get from your RDBMS, IDE, interpreter, or otherwise? Also, please share your table definition.

Comment: Add this line after query execution line, so that we can see what is the error:
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($db));

Comment: The last field added is a date field. Maybe you must take care of a NULL value when empty?

Comment: This is the error "scription: Incorrect date value: '' for column `15daytkt`.`nma_raw`.`Resolved_Date` at row 1"

Comment: I dont understand how that could be because I put no data in that field and the default is empty. It is also not a required field.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641096/error-while-inserting-date-incorrect-date-value

Comment: Please wrap the queries.  And highlight what is different between them!  You need to escape strings before building a query.  Don't blindly use `TEXT` for virtually everything, pick appropriate datatypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error you're getting is `Incorrect date value: '' for column 15daytkt.nma_raw.Resolved_Date` (as you've mentioned in the comments) :

It looks like you are passing an empty string to the `Resolved_Date` column, and it's invalid. Please make sure you're actually passing a valid `date` string in this format `2019-11-15`. Usually, the HTML form inputs with the `date` type return this format.

You can verify this case by setting the value to `NULL` if it's empty. Try changing the query as below:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db,"update nma_raw set NMA_System='$nmasystem', Resolved_Date=NULLIF($resolved_date, '') WHERE ID='$id'");
```

Note the `NULLIF($resolved_date, '')` part. It will basically set the value to `null` if it is empty.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the answer!!!! The string was empty and it needed to remain so upon updating the record. The form did return the correct datetype if data was there. I will correct the text datatypes also. Thanks for your help!