# Insert date object from python to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, date

I'm inserting data from python into a mysql table.

The table that I am trying to insert in mysql has different data type such as `varchar`, `decimal` and `date`.

My understanding is that `mysql.connector` api handles the data conversion from python to sql table.

However I get the following error:

> Incorrect date value: '01/01/2015' for column 'reporting_pd' at row 1. The data type for the variable reporting_pd is of date type in the database.

The following is code snippet I am using:

```py
table = 'performance'
column_names = 'loan_indentifier, reporting_pd, servicer, current_interest_rate, current_UPB, loan_age, remaining_months_maturity'
inputs = ', '.join(['%s' for column in list(sample)])
insert_query = "insert into {} ({}) values ({})".format(table, column_names, inputs)
values = ("100002091588","01/01/2015"", "OTHER", "4.125", "nan", "0", "360")

mycursor.execute(insert_query, (values))
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Try having look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11641203/3531672

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to format your date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Answer (score 1):

> 01/01/2015

This is not a supported date format. The `DATE` type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays `DATE` values in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. The supported range is `1000-01-01` to `9999-12-31`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html