# Incorrect date value: '2022-06-11T00:00:00.000Z' for column 'date' at row 1

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, datetime

**This is my NodeJs API that is connected to my MySQL workbench**

```
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "12112002suman",
    database:"chutiyadb",
});


// app.get('/' , (req,res) => {
//     res.send("connected to database"); 
// });

db.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err
});

function insertData(Title,Amount,Date){
    db.query('INSERT INTO expenseitems (title, amount , date) VALUES ( ? , ? , ?)',
    [Title, Amount, Date], function (err, result) {  
           if (err) throw err; 
});
}

app.post('/api/insert', function(req,res) {


    insertData(req.body.title, req.body.amount,  req.body.date);
}); 
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log(" running on port 3001");
});
```

I'm trying to take Date input by using calender format from a user that is

> 08-06-2022 as dd-mm-yyyy

Error is

> "Incorrect date value: '2022-06-11T00:00:00.000Z' for column 'date' at row 1"

Comment: proly you need to convert date input to MySql format as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11641203/4149861)

Answer (score 2):

Convert Your current date format into your required date format using the **moment** library.

first, install the moment library

```
 npm i moment
```

then, convert the date format

```
let current_date = moment('Your date input').format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss - your required date format");
```